# Everlasting java object

Tags: java

Is it possible to create an object which will be alive till the JVM is not shut down? Or is there any java objects which remains alive till the JVM is not shutdown.

Comment: Please describe for what purpose you need this object?

Comment: Do you mean "alive untill the JVM is shutdown"? The JVM "is not shutdown" whenever it is running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can be fairly certain that a `static` field will not be garbage collected. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453023/are-static-fields-open-for-garbage-collection) for details.

Comment: As soon as the class has been loaded :)

Answer (score 1):

The main Thread of your program is always alive until the JVM shuts down.

Why are you asking this question ?

Comment: Actually, this is incorrect.  If your `main` method creates and starts other (non-daemon) threads, and then it returns, the JVM will keep running until the other threads die ... or something calls `System.exit(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  All you have to do is make sure the object is reachable by running code, and it won't die.  The GC only collects stuff that the code doesn't have a reference to anymore.

A single static reference (that you never set to null) within one of your classes should be enough to guarantee that the object sticks around as long as the app is running.  However, as long as you are able to see and use the object, it should stick around anyway.  (There's a concept called "weak references" that makes this *not always* true, but if you're using them, then you wouldn't be asking the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Every JVM instance has only one `java.lang.Runtime` instance. Created at the start and stays till the end. If you want everlasting then there are two ways:

1. Override `protected void finalize() throws Throwable;` and Self reference the object in it.
2. Maintain reference to your object