# Why is this static field null?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver

on android.
my activity is like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   static TextView textview;
   static int aaa = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
```

//other method,startservice()and so on.

and there is BroadcastReceiver to receive a flag from service.

```
     public static class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intents) {
        intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        textview.setText("set")//throw null point
                    Log.d("aaa","aaa is" + aaa);
```

like this, in onReceiver, textview is  null.
as test, int aaa is'nt null.

why textview is null?

EDIT
Texttiew xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

And method in Activity using same textview.settext isnt null.
Thanks.

EDIT2 
I can know i should save this variable.
So, whats the best way to save VIEW variable?
SharedPreferences seem not able to save VIEW variable.

Comment: What does your layout XML look like?

Answer (score 1):

This thread indicates that having static fields might be a problem. 
In general, android kills your app.. and on return static variables may not be set.

[static variable null when returning to the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541688/static-variable-null-when-returning-to-the-app)

Comment: Oh,,,i forgot im using webview with VIEW.GONE.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely that you are not referencing the correct textview element. Double check your IDs in your layout file.