# Saving last state of an Android Activity on Home Press

Tags: android, restart

When i press **home button** on my app, it will take me to the `desktop menu`. And when i open it again the last state is not maintained. `Last state of the Activity is not saved`. Whereas it normally should save the last state on Home Press. Why is it so?

Comment: You mean you want to exit app on pressing Home? So next time you want the app to be started again?

Comment: please post some more useful information.

Comment: its very difficult to understand your question.

Comment: I mean I am pressing the home key, and then click the program's desktop icon again ,it should come back before UI,but it not.

Comment: Android kill your Activity whenever it needs space/memory. you may have less memory or running multiple apps at one time

Comment: Don't press desktop icon again . Hold home button for 2 sec ..Your running app will shown to you. then open it  and you are good to go..

Comment: What kind of thing do you want to save and make visible when you re-open your app? Is it text data or something else?

Comment: can u please elaborate your question @Gray not clear

Comment: Check this Answer it contains code sample:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25400275/1826581

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment . you are opening another desktop icon while your app is running in background. it means you are opening a new instance. Follow steps.

1. After pressing home button you move to desktop menu.
2. **Press and hold home button** again for two/three seconds . Your app will be shown to you in a small screen at the botton . Select it, it will show you the last state **if and only if** Android doesn't kill it for memory/space.
3. And you can also save state of an Activity by setting a variable in Manifest which will always  hold that activity in memory and save it state.

Answer (score 0):

Override the [onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) in your activity and save the UI state to the supplied Bundle. This function is called when your activity is stopped.

When the application later is restarted use a overridden [onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) to read the saved data and setup the UI to the correct state.

Cheers!