# When Android app process gets killed app crashes when resuming

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onresume

When my apps gets killed because other apps need the resources and I return to the app, I get a NullPointerException. I tried to solve this by checking this within the onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (aanvraag == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.pager, new StartFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately,this doesn't seem to work. The idea is that the entire workflow of the app restarts (by launching my StartFragment).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

The app crashes in one of the fragments within the activity. One where the object aanvraag is being used.

**Logcat:**

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nl.emconsult.wbso/nl.emconsult.wbso.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at nl.emconsult.wbso.fragments.ResultatenFragment.vulVelden(ResultatenFragment.java:138)
at nl.emconsult.wbso.fragments.ResultatenFragment.onCreateView(ResultatenFragment.java:61)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2046)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:174)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:598)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1165)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5127)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
... 11 more
```

**Resultatenfragment (or at least stripped from all the irrelevant details):**

```
public class ResultatenFragment extends Fragment {

public ResultatenFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.resultaten_fragment, container, false);

    boolean someVariable = vulVelden(rootView);

    return rootView;

}

    private boolean vulVelden(View rootView) {
    //Perform some calculations, store some and display some values and return true if everything works out allright. 
    aanvraag.doSomething(); //This is ResultatenFragment.java:138, where I get the NullPointerException 
    return (true);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to share what you have in onStop() and post your logcat. As it is right now, it is hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: I have no override for onStop()

Comment: Can you show the code around ResultatenFragment.java:138 ?

Comment: I added the code of ResultatenFragment (or at least the important part) and I indicated where I get the NullPointerException)

Comment: You should take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9541769/3533289

Comment: @The_Martian: Does the extra info help?

Comment: @MuchOverflow: I looked at the post and it seems they suggest to implement onResume(). That is what I am trying, but this doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: By the way, I use an ActionBarActivity. Does that change things?

Comment: @MWB You should save your class in state at `onSavedInstanceState()` and restore it when the app comes back on `onCreateView()`

Comment: @MuchOverflow: Thanks that did the job!

Comment: @MWB Glad to help :)