# does "object" in kotlin get garbage collected

Tags: android, kotlin, object, garbage-collection, singleton

If we have an **Object** like this

```
object Repo { var activeMovies: ArrayList<Movie>? = null }
```

and then we call it like this to assign a value

```
Repo.activeMovies = movieList
```

after the **Activity** that instantiated it is finish, does it get **Garbage Collected**?

I know this may be very basic question but I cannot understand the lifecycle if the `object` type in **Kotlin**.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If we create an object like this:

```
object Test {
    // some functions and properties
}
```

and decompile it to **Java**, we will see next code:

```
public final class Test {
    public static final Test INSTANCE;

   static {
      Test var0 = new Test();
      INSTANCE = var0;
   }
}
```

From the decompiled code, we can see that `object` creates a **Singleton**. The initialization happens on a **static block**. In **Java**, static blocks are executed on class loading time. The instance of `Test` class is created at the moment when the classloader loads the class. This approach guarantees **lazy-loading** and **thread-safety**. An instance of a singleton object is kept in a static field inside the class of that object. Therefore it isn’t eligible to the garbage collection. The `Test` is a **Singleton**, whose lifespan is as long as the lifespan of an app.

Here are some useful information about static variables [Android static object lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944369/android-static-object-lifecycle/1944564#1944564) and [static variable null when returning to the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541688/static-variable-null-when-returning-to-the-app).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the explanation. Very helpful indeed.

Comment: little clarification - if you have some way to close a classloader used to load such singletons, it will be GCed eventually. It, highly likely, could require making of a custom classloader.