# Should I persist data with SqlLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm confused about when to persist data in mobile development. AT this stage I'm initializing a table with some values that will not change. Is there an advantage to storing this data in a table as opposed to initializing a list containing the data every time I want to access it? It just seems like a lot of work storing data to a table and retrieving it and I don't want to do unnecssary work if there's no advantages.

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of data you are saving?

Comment: I am adding two strings (title and url), which are used to initialize an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to depends on the amount and complexity of your data.

If you have much data or the data you actually have can grow you should use `SQLite`.

If you just have some configuration data like if you can notify the user or something like this or some string which is your case  you should use `SharePreference`.

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529787/6727154

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like you have any changing data (CRUD) so I wouldn't use SQLite. Look into SharedPrefs as @Michael stated.