# Can garbage Collector deallocate singleton instance? (and why or how to avoid it)

Tags: android, garbage-collection, singleton, dealloc

In Android I have singleton class but I am not sure if the garbage Collector can deallocate it.

If garbage Collector will deallocate my singleton class how can avoid it from deallocation?

Comment: There is convention of using WeakReference, try to use that.

Answer (score 3):

Garbage collection collects objects that nothing is pointed to, unless a reference is static. [Are static fields open for garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453023/are-static-fields-open-for-garbage-collection)

Comment: There is no such thing, in Java, as a "static object".

Comment: An object's structure cannot be declared static, but you can have a static reference/instance of it. Answer edited to say reference.

Comment: Yeah!  I think, though, that you could just leave out the whole thing about static references.  Your answer is complete and correct, at the comma!

Answer (score 2):

The only reason gc will dealocate your instance is if the entire app is destroyed...

Comment: This is patently false:  Consider:  `static { new Object(); }`  That is a singleton and it is garbage collected instantly.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to implement a Singleton.  One of the best is:

```
public static enum My { SINGLETON; }
```

Whether or not something is a singleton has no bearing on whether it is GCed or not.  An object will be GCed if there are no Strong references to it.  Look it up (http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references).

There is one more issue that is of interest.  In Android, your application does not control it's lifecycle.  It is possible that a process will be terminated and re-created in ways you do not expect.  If that happens, static final variables will be re-initialized.  There's more on that here:

http://portabledroid.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/singletons-in-android/