# static vs non static

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Until few weeks back, I thought I understand when to make fields and methods `static` or `non-static`. For example, when a field (say object of another class) is unique for any number of objects for the class, it should be made `static`.

But then I read about JVM garbage collection a few weeks back.

I understand that `static` fields are never garbage collected and remain in memory all along, unless the class loader itself is garbage collected.

But if I don't make that field `static`, at least it will be garbage collected.

So, it seems there is a ***very thin line*** between making fields/methods static or not.

Can anybody please explain to me this ***thin line*** in deciding, so that my application is way more efficient.

Comment: And what's the problem with the field not being garbage collected? You want it available for the lifetime of the application, don't you? So it's prettty normal for the object not being GCed. Applications consume memory. It's normal and expected. Setting it to null will make it available for GC (unless it's reachable from somewhere else).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be thin but there is very clear distinction. You declare a field as static when it is not at all related to any instance of a class.

A simple usecase of static field is declaring constants using `final` keyword, e.g.:

```
public static final int MAX_ALLOWED = 10;
```

Same is the case with methods also. You declare a method as static when it is not dependent on  instance of a class OR the state of the class. That's the reason a static method cannot use instance members of a class.

Comment: Also check [this answer for more details on Garbage Collection of static variable.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/453061/548225)

Comment: what I understand from here is, if that field's life is long, then its ok to make it static, on the other hand, if only one instance is required but life is very short. Then its ok to make it non-static.

Comment: @Batty: Yes very true and also the size of the static object should also be considered. If it is a tiny size object then making it static won't hurt your memory.

Answer (score 3):

These are not mandatory rules, but it is better to follow them:

When to use static fields:

1. **Constants** Best usage of static fields are constants, which shall be `final` too.
2. **ThreadLocals** Most of the time you define thread-local variables static, otherwise you usually lose the reference to them. But don't forget to release their contents when there is no more use (or you will encounter memory leaks). Most of the time these variables are *final* too.
3. And very rare cases when you shall keep a reference to a (semantically) singleton object which could be accessed from many places. (For example a reference to Hibernate `SessionFactory` in HibernateUtils).

Remember that, static fields shall usually be immutable during runtime of your application (they are sometimes modified during start-up and tear-down of the application).

When to use static methods:

1. **Helper utility methods** that's the normal case, when a method does not depend on state of its containing object. These methods can be useful, and can be accessed without instantiating any object.
2. **Factory methods** Factory methods are another good example of where to use static methods.
3. **Private methods which are not depend on objects state**, when a private method just have no dependency on object's state, it is much better to define it `static` to gain a little performance.
4. **void main(String[])** method shall be static too.

Comment: Inner static enums are also acceptable, but I think that'd fall under the umbrella of a constant.

Comment: In fact they are inner static classes, which are not bad at all.

Answer (score 3):

Static fields is a **concept** you should really think carefully about before using it as a method to increase the efficiency of your application.

As you know when static modifier is included in a field , no instance of the class is required for it to be used. And as a result it has a the same value for the entire application. On one hand it can lead to many bugs in multi-threaded read/write environment if you don't properly serialize  the access, on the other hand it is good thing if you trying to create  [singleton pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html) (A field with a value that do not change during the life time of the application and therefor **do not need to be GC**)

By and large you should avoid read/write static fields, it will introduce more bugs into your application. Having the same value across many instances of the same class is not considered a good use case for static field in OO design. Not because it is less or more efficient but because it breaks the concept of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

Fields are not made `static` over garbage collection. That is whole new area to consider. If the memory is huge for your `static` field, yeah you should make it `non-static`.

Comment: You shouldn't make it non static if the size in memory is large because then you get more than one of it. Instead, you should make it static and have a mechanism to clear it when you aren't using it. Or just deal with it because making a new one might take a long time.

Comment: @Radiodef - That'll be on way.