# Is Static Variable will be garbage collected? if not why?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is Static Variable will be collected by garbage collection? If not please let me know the reason for it.

Comment: It seems to me [this question and associated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453023/are-static-fields-open-for-garbage-collection) should help you out.