# Can Collections.unmodifiableMap retain the original map?

Tags: java, dictionary, garbage-collection, unmodifiable

I have a piece of code below:

```
class Util {
    private static final Map<String, String> MY_MAP;

    static {
        Map<String, String> tmpMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        tmpMap.put("key1", "val1");
        tmpMap.put("key2", "val2");
        tmpMap.put("key3", "val3");

        MY_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmpMap);
    }

    public static String getVal(String key) {
        return MY_MAP.get(key);
    }
}
```

Can MY_MAP retain the tmpMap always? Or in other words, is it possible that the GC will recycle the tmpMap which makes the MY_MAP inaccessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned Map is just a "view" which wraps around the Map passed in.

So yes, `tmpMap` will be retained as long as `MY_MAP` is alive. Since `MY_MAP` is a `static final` field, `tmpMap` will be retained [basically *forever*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453023/are-static-fields-open-for-garbage-collection).

[`unmodifiableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-):

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified map. [...] Query operations on the returned map "read through" to the specified map [...].

Answer (score 3):

> Or in other words, is it possible that the GC will recycle the tmpMap which makes the MY_MAP inaccessible?

No, never. `MY_MAP` has a (strong) reference to `tmpMap`, so it can't be collected.

In general, the GC will never do anything like this. You'll never see it working, except in special cases (`WeakHashMap` and similar).