# When does object reference variable will be eligible for garbage collection when it is being declared as final

Tags: java

Here is my code snippet where i am using a final object reference..

```
public class FinalTest{
    private int rollNo;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final FinalTest obj = new FinalTest();
        obj.rollNo=20;

        obj.rollNo=30;

        System.out.println(obj.rollNo);
        obj = null; 

    }
}
```

and finally i am assigning null to the reference variable obj.. 
but java does not allow this. so i want to know in such case ( when we 
don't assign null to our object reference obj) when 
does this obj will become eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: `obj = null;` wouldn't compile, would it? [demo](http://ideone.com/gD0dtJ)

Comment: no it would not. that's what i'm asking.. if we are not allowed to mark a final variable to null, then when it will become eligible for garbage collection ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object, which `obj` holds reference to, should become eligible for garbage collection when the method completes, because the program flow should be already on a different execution scope (i.e. other method/class)

Comment: i got it. but now i have got one more doubt. what would happen if i create the object like this..   final static FinalTest obj = new FinalTest(). in this case i am creating this object as an instance variable. then when it will become eligible for garbage collection ?

Comment: The "`obj` reference" is never garbage collected. It's a variable. The object to which it points becomes eligible when there are not further references to it.

Comment: @AndyThomas i understood what you said. but here the object is being pointed by the obj reference type which is final so that means this object will be engaged to obj forever as we can't set obj to null explicitly because it is being marked final. so in such case when would my object which is being pointed by obj will become eligible for garbage collection ?

Comment: Your local variable `obj` goes out of scope at the end of its method. Its lifetime is shorter than forever.

Comment: @AndyThomas you are right. i understood what you said. but would you please tell me what would be the case if i declare  the object like this:-  final static FinalTest obj = new FinalTest();. here i have decared it as an instance variable. now when this object will be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @VijendarThakur - To be more precise, that would declare a static field that contains a reference to a newly created object. (You'd need to move the line outside the method.) Static fields are *class variables* rather than instance variables. The field will live as long as the class, preventing collection of the object it references. More detail is in the existing question ["Are static fields open to garbage collection?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453023/are-static-fields-open-for-garbage-collection).