# NoClassDefFoundError on JFace FontRegistry

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

When I launch an SWT application (via an Eclipse launch profile), I receive the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jface/resource/FontRegistry
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources.getFontRegistry(JFaceResources.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.close(Window.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.close(Dialog.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.close(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.finishedRun(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:498)
    at com.blah.si.workflow.SWTApplication.main(SWTApplication.java:135)
```

Now, the things that make this odd:

1. When I change the project build path and replace jface.jar with the source project (same version - 3.3.1), the error goes away.
2. Other applications I have that use the same jar, and a copy of the same launch profile and project, all works fine.
3. This is **NOT** a `ClassNotFoundException`.  The class is on the classpath.  If I attach source to the jar, I can debug into the getFontRegistry method.  The method will execute successfully several times before eventually throwing a `NoClassDefFoundError` on line 338.  Line 337 is a "if variable == null" statement checking to see if a static variable has been initialized.  Line 338 is initializing it if it is not already initialized.  The first time through, the null check fails, and the initialization is performed.  On subsequent passes through the method, the null check passes, and thus the already-initialized static value is returned.  On the final pass (the one that fails,) the null check fails again (even though the static variable has already been initialized) and when it tries to re-initialize the static variable, the `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown.  Here is the relevant source (starting with line 336, note that fontRegistry is a private static variable that is set in no other place):

.

```
public static FontRegistry getFontRegistry() {
   if (fontRegistry == null) {
     fontRegistry = new FontRegistry(
         "org.eclipse.jface.resource.jfacefonts");
   }
   return fontRegistry;
}
```

.

1. I have already gotten a fresh copy of the jar (to ensure it isn't corrupted,) deleted my .classpath and .project files and started a fresh project, and recreated the launch profile.  No change.

Because of the peculiarities in #3 above, I'm suspecting some kind of wierd classloader behavior - it seems as if that final pass through the method is in another classloader?

Ideas?

**Update:**  The answer provided by Pourquoi Litytestdata prompted me to pay attention to what happens in the try block just above line 458 of ProgressMonitorDialog.  Indeed, that code was throwing an exception, which was being gobbled by the finally block.  The root cause was ANOTHER missing class (the missing class was not JFontRegistry or any of its directly related classes, but another that was spider-web dependencied in an edge case.)  I'm upvoting all answers pointing me to pay attention to the classpath, and accepting Pourquoi's, because it was the breakthrough.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the stacktrace presented above is concealing the real problem here.  Below is the code in the method `run` within
[org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/ProgressMonitorDialog.java.htm) (with a comment added by me):

```
public void run(boolean fork, boolean cancelable,
         IRunnableWithProgress runnable) throws InvocationTargetException,
         InterruptedException {
     setCancelable(cancelable);
     try {
         aboutToRun();
         // Let the progress monitor know if they need to update in UI Thread
         progressMonitor.forked = fork;
         ModalContext.run(runnable, fork, getProgressMonitor(), getShell()
                 .getDisplay());
     } finally {
         finishedRun();  // this is line 498
     }
}
```

The second-from-bottom line in Jared's stacktrace is line 498 of this class, which is the call to `finishedRun()` within the `finally` block.  I suspect that the real cause is an exception being thrown in the `try` block.  Since the code in the `finally` block also throws an exception, the original exception is lost.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are missing a JAR file that holds a dependency, as mentioned in this blog entry from July 2006, written by [**Sanjiv JIVAN**](http://www.jroller.com/sjivan/):

[**Difference between ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError**](http://www.jroller.com/sjivan/entry/difference_between_classnotfoundexception_and_noclassdeffounderror)

> A **`ClassNotFoundException`** is thrown when the reported class is not found by the ClassLoader.
>   This typically means that the class is missing from the `CLASSPATH`.
>   It could also mean that the class in question is trying to be loaded from another class which was loaded in a parent `ClassLoader` and hence the class from the child `ClassLoader` is not visible.
>   This is sometimes the case when working in more complex environments like an App Server (WebSphere is infamous for such `ClassLoader` issues).
>
> People often tend to confuse **`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`** with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. However there's an important distinction.
>
> For example an exception (an error really since **`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`** is a subclass of **`java.lang.Error`**) like

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory
```

> does not mean that the ActiveMQConnectionFactory class is not in the `CLASSPATH`.
>
> In fact, its quite the opposite.
>
> **It means that the class `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` was found by the `ClassLoader` however when trying to load the class, it ran into an error reading the class definition.**
>
> **This typically happens when the class in question has static blocks or members which use a Class that's not found by the `ClassLoader`.**
>
> So to find the culprit, view the source of the class in question (`ActiveMQConnectionFactory` in this case) and **look for code using static blocks or static members**.
>   If you don't have access the the source, then simply decompile it using **[JAD](http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html)**.
>
> On examining the code, say you find a line of code like below, make sure that the class SomeClass in in your `CLASSPATH`.

```
private static SomeClass foo = new SomeClass();
```

> Tip : To find out which jar a class belongs to, you can use the web site **[jarFinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/)**.  This allows you to specify a class name using wildcards and it searches for the class in its database of jars.
>   [jarhoo](http://www.jarhoo.com/) allows you to do the same thing but its no longer free to use.
>
> If you would like to locate the which jar a class belongs to in a local path, you can use a utility like **[jarscan](http://www.inetfeedback.com/jarscan/)**. You just specify the class you'd like to locate and the root directory path where you'd like it to start searching for the class in jars and zip files.

Comment: @TofuBeer: I took the liberty to add the full article: if the link is one day no more active, this excellent blog will survive in here. +1 for this link, and I believe this may very well be the official solution for Jared's question.

Comment: I've already looked at the source and debugged through - there is no exception being thrown during static initialization (in fact, the class is successfully initialized and its instance members are used successfully several times prior to the failure.)

Answer (score 2):

To get a better handle on if it is a class loader issue go through the code where it works and add:

```
try
{
    final Class       clazz;
    final ClassLoader loader;

    clazz  = Class.forName("org/eclipse/jface/resource/FontRegistry");
    loader = clazz.getClassLoader(); 
    System.out.println("The classloader at step 1 is: " + loader);
}
catch(final Throwable ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

And then do the same thing where you are getting the NoClassDefFoundError and see if the class loaders are different.

Then you will be able to ensure that it is the ClassLoader that is different.  Can you report back with what happens with this?  Depending on what the result is I might have more ideas.

Comment: +1 for the help in troubleshooting classloader stuff - even though that didn't turn out to be the problem.  My bad for throwing out the red herring.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the [excellent TofuBeer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596999/noclassdeffounderror-on-jface-fontregistry/597781#597781), since `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that:

- class **`org.eclipse.jface.resource.FontRegistry`** *was found* by the `ClassLoader`,
- but **can not been loaded without triggering an error, like having static blocks or members which use a `Class` that's not found by the `ClassLoader`**.

Let's look at [**`org.eclipse.jface.resource.FontRegistry`** source code](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/resource/FontRegistry.java.htm):

It does not have any static variable initialization (nor does its superclasses).

Let's look at **[`org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources` source code](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jface/resource/JFaceResources.java.htm)**

The `getFontRegistry()` function in which the Error is triggered is using the **static variable fontRegistry**:

```
/**
 * The JFace font registry; <code>null</code> until lazily initialized or
 * explicitly set.
 */
private static FontRegistry fontRegistry = null;
```

Thus, it <strike>begs</strike> *raises* the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405364/whats-up-with-static-memory-in-java): why a [static initialized variable](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#19075) would suddenly be considered `null` again ?

Because somehow [`FontRegistry` or `JFaceResources` get unloaded by the gc](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread34695-3.html) ?!

> If a field is declared static, there exists exactly one incarnation of the field, no matter how many instances (possibly zero) of the class may eventually be created. A static field, sometimes called a class variable, is incarnated when the class is initialized (§12.4).
>
> So it doesn't matter whether instances of the class exist at any time, the field will exist as long as the Class itself has been loaded.

---

If this were a **eclipse Plugin**, this could have been related to this **[FAQ entry](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_causes_my_plug-in_to_build_but_not_to_load_in_a_runtime_workbench%3F)**

> Here is a typical scenario for a new user:
>   You are writing a plug-in that extends plug-in XYZ.
>   To get it to compile, you add a reference to the JAR file for plug-in XYZ to your project’s build path either from the Java Build Path property page or by editing the .classpath file.
>   When you launch a runtime workbench, the following surprising error is reported: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: XYZ.SomeClass`.
>
> Do not start looking in the Plug-ins and Fragments tab in the launch configuration for the runtime workbench.
>   That tab influences only which plug-ins are used for your runtime workbench and whether they are loaded from the workspace or from the Eclipse install directory.
>
> Instead, start looking in the plug-in manifest.
>   **Edit the plugin.xml file and ensure that XYZ is mentioned as a required plug-in**.
>   Then, save the plugin.xml file.
>   This will update the project’s build path automatically.
>
> Never manually edit the .classpath file when you are writing a plug-in.
>   The plug-in Manifest Editor simply overwrites any changes you make to it. Not very civilized, but that is the way it works.

Comment: I'm not writing a plugin - so I don't think this applies.  I'm simply using SWT/JFace as a regular old jar in my regular old project.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to load the class FontRegistry on your own (like TofoBeer described), you will find out that classes of the following JAR are dependent classes if using FontRegistry.

```
org.eclipse.core.commands_xxxxx.jar
```

You must add this JAR to your build path.