# In which memory static variables,local variables are presents?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Whats up with static memory in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405364/whats-up-with-static-memory-in-java)
>   [What is the actual memory place for static variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569557/what-is-the-actual-memory-place-for-static-variables)

In which memory static variables,local variables are presents like object is leave in heap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a **heap** dump you get all the static values.  The heap dump shows that static fields are in a special object for that class.  You can access this "object" in the Sun/Oracle JVM by using the Unsafe class.

While local values are on the stack, eg. a reference, any object this references in on the heap.  (Unlike languages like C++)

e.g.

```
String hi = "hello";
```

The reference `hi` in on the stack but the Object (which is most of the memory) is in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

static variables -> perm gen
local variables-> stack